# What’s this tool

Tags: hand-tools

[image: Tool]

I don’t know what this tool is or what is called

Comment: They look like some sort of snips. Could you upload a more focused photo perhaps ?

Comment: it looks like a Motorola modem ... it is in focus and well lit ... why don't you hold the tool there and take a picture?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bad picture (out of focus, neither end of the tool is in the picture...) of snap-ring pliers, from the lower-quality tier, such as these ones from Harbor Freight... Which I usually call Horrible Fright for their overall attention to quality, but they do manage cheap in every sense.

[image: internal snap-ring plier image from Harbor Freight]

Provide a better picture and you might get a more accurate identification. Show the **whole** tool, against a neutral background that does not blend with it, and provide clear, legible closeups of any writing or engraving on the tool, and of its working end.

Given the working end is out of the picture, could be several other tools in the "tong" and "plier" families.